# Getting nodes from html page using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, nodes, html-agility-pack

My program collects info about Steam users' profiles (such as games, badges and etc.). 
I use `HtmlAgilityPack` to collect data from html page and so far it worked for me just good.

The problem is that on some pages it works well, but on some - returns null nodes or throws an exception

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here's an example.

This part works well (when I'm getting badges):

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string html = client.DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/*id*/badges/");

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        HtmlNodeCollection div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"badge_row is_link\"]");
```

This returns the exact amout of badges and then I can do whatever I want with them.

But in this one I do the exact same thing (but getting games), and somehow it keeps throwing me and error I mentioned above:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string html = client.DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/*id*/games/?tab=all");

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        HtmlNodeCollection div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='game_33120']");
```

I know that there is the node on the page (checked via google chrome code view) and I don't know why in 1st case it works, but in the 2nd it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you right-click on the page and choose View Source do you still see an element with id='game_33120'?  My guess is you won't.  My guess is that the page is being built dynamically, client-side.  Therefore, the HTML that comes down in the request doesn't contain the element you're looking for.  Instead that element appears once the Javascript code has run in the browser.

It appears that the original request will have a section of Javascript that contains a variable called rgGames which is a Javascript array of the games that will be rendered on the screen.  You should be able to extract the information from that.

Comment: Yes, when I click View Source I see this element. But the thing is when I save html page local and then reopen it - I dont see the list of games, so I think you're absolutely right with Javascript answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the selectNodes method with this parameter "//*[@id='game_33120']", maybe is this your fault, but you can check this:

1. The real link of an steamprofil with batches etc is:

> http://steamcommunity.com/id/*id*/badges/

and not

> http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/*id*/badges/

2. after I visited an badges page, the url stay in the browser, at the games link, they redirect you to

> http:// steamcommunity. com

Maybe this can help you